# How to setup subdomain on the nuxt js with pm2?

Tags: server, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I got problem when setup subdomain on the server with nuxt js.

I have setup /etc/hosts and put 127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost then restart the nginx server and restart the pm2. And the main domain not using localhost:3000, so port is available. But I still got an error.

Error says: *Server error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.*

how can I solve this? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pm2 has nothing to do with domain or subdomain.
As I understand, you want to proxy your nuxt app to a subdomain.

You have to launch your nuxt app with pm2:
`pm2 start 'nuxt start'`

and proxy localhost:3000 to your domain or subdomain like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Plesk installed and using Plesk I have setup subdomain and put nuxt app there, seem to work. There are many ways Plesk is one way. To start app I used https://nuxtjs.org/faq/deployment-pm2/